# How to write the xpath expression?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

```
text = '''\
<html>
    <body>
        <p><strong>test</strong>TEXT A B </p>
        <p><strong>test</strong>TEXT A </p>
        <p><strong>test</strong>TEXT B </p>
        <p><strong>ok</strong>TEXT A B </p>
        <p>TEXT A B </p>
    <body>
</html>'''
import lxml.html
root = lxml.html.fromstring(text)
```

There are three p nodes in html-text, i want to extract `<p><strong>test</strong>TEXT A B </p>` as desired.

The features are :

1.the text value of p element contains `A` and `B`.
2.the text value of p's sub element `strong` is `test`.

```
node = root.xpath('.//p[contains(text(),"A") and contains(text(),"B")]')
```

The above expression will extract the three nodes,i have a try with xpath:

```
node = root.xpath('.//p[/strong(contains(text(),"test")) and contains(text(),"A") and contains(text(),"B")]')
```

It is a invalid expression in xpath,how to write the right format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A correct XPath expression given your requirements is

```
//p[contains(., 'A') and contains(., 'B') and strong/text() = 'test']"
```

**Python output**

```
>>> root.xpath("//p[contains(., 'A') and contains(., 'B') and strong/text() = 'test']")
[<Element p at 0x1075031b0>]
```

**Problem with your proposed approaches**

Your first solution does not include all conditions (text content of `strong` is missing), while the second one includes `strong()` (you probably meant `strong[]`).

Your second proposed approach can be amended with minimal changes, with the same output:

```
>>>> root.xpath('//p[strong[contains(text(),"test")] and contains(text(),"A") and contains(text(),"B")]')
[<Element p at 0x1075031b0>]
```

The difference to my solution above being that I test for the string value `.`, while your solution has `text()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try a solution other than XPath, and you may like it, too.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''<html>
    <body>
        <p><strong>test</strong>TEXT A B </p>
        <p><strong>test</strong>TEXT A </p>
        <p><strong>test</strong>TEXT B </p>
        <p><strong>ok</strong>TEXT A B </p>
        <p>TEXT A B </p>
    <body>
</html>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
ps = doc.selects('p').contains(['<strong>test</strong>','A','B'])
print (ps)
```

Result:

```
[{'tag': 'p', 'html': '<strong>test</strong>TEXT A B '}]
```

You can also try the following code to see what is output.

```
print (doc.selects('p').containsOr(['<strong>test</strong>','<strong>ok</strong>']))
print (doc.selects('p').notContains(['<strong>test</strong>','<strong>ok</strong>']))
```